# Problema al evaluar con File.Exists()

Tags: c#, filesystem, system.io

Estoy tratando de crear un respaldo en excel con los datos cargados en un DataGridView, pero al momento de validar si existe el archivo valida mal. Cuando el archivo no existe, valida bien y lo crea, pero cuando el archivo ya existe intenta crearlo lo mismo. Estoy usando visual studio 2017.

Este es el codigo del metodo que crea el respaldo:

```
public void respaldarInfo(DataGridView dgv)
{
    Service_Inscripcion service = new Service_Inscripcion();
    DateTimeFormatInfo fecha = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();

    //variable para crear o buscar la carpeta donde se va a guardar el respaldo en excel.
    //Dentro de la carpeta Respaldo Sport Gym, se van a crear subCarpetas con el formato: "nombre del mes" "año"
    string ruta = "C:\\Respaldo Sport Gym\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM") + " " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    //variable para darle nombre al excel con el formato: "dia"-"mes"-"año"
    string excel = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    //variable que junta la ruta de la carpeta + la ruta que deberia tener el archivo a crear.
    string rutaFinal = ruta + "\\" + excel; ;

    IList<DTO_Inscripcion> inscripciones = service.getInscripciones();
    if (!Directory.Exists(ruta) && dgv != null)//valida que la carpeta no exista
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);//en caso de no existir se crea

        //Valida que la lista tenga valores para guardar
        if (inscripciones != null && inscripciones.Count > 0)
        {
            crearExcel(dgv,inscripciones,rutaFinal);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para guardar", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    else//este else se ejecuta si el directorio donde se crean los respaldos existe.
    {
        if (inscripciones != null && inscripciones.Count > 0)//valida que la lista que llena el DataGridView tenga datos
        {
            if(!File.Exists(rutaFinal))//valida que el archivo no haya sido creado ya
            {
                crearExcel(dgv, inscripciones, rutaFinal);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para guardar", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el código del método que crea el excel, por si hay algún error en este método que afecte al otro:

```
private void crearExcel(DataGridView dgv, IList<DTO_Inscripcion> inscripciones, string rutaFinal)
{
    //try para capturar algun error que pueda suceder al momento de crear y dar formato al Excel
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
        aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
        hoja_trabajo =
            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        //nombre de las columnas del excel
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "A"] = "Nº Inscripcion";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "B"] = "Orden";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "C"] = "Socio";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "D"] = "Nombre";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "E"] = "Apellido";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "F"] = "Vencimiento";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "G"] = "Estado";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "H"] = "Fecha Pago";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "I"] = "Hora Ingreso";
        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "J"] = "Hora Egreso";
        //formato de la hoja
        hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "J" + (dgv.Rows.Count) + 1.ToString()].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "J1"].Font.Bold = true;
        hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "J1"].Font.Size = 16;
        hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "J1"].Interior.ColorIndex = 17;
        hoja_trabajo.Range["A2", "J2" + (dgv.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()].Font.Size = 12;
        hoja_trabajo.Columns.AutoFit();
        //

        //linea que guarda el archivo
        libros_trabajo.SaveAs(rutaFinal, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
        libros_trabajo.Close(true);
        aplicacion.Quit();
        MessageBox.Show("El respaldo se realizo correctamente", "Exito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar generar el archivo Excel", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

He puesto un punto de interrupción para ver que devuelve `File.Exists()` y siempre retorna `false`, aun existiendo el archivo.
He forzado a que entre por true o false de las siguientes maneras:

```
if(!File.Exists(rutaFinal))//valida que el archivo no haya sido creado ya
{
    crearExcel(dgv, inscripciones, rutaFinal);
}
```

y acá sacando el !

```
if(File.Exists(rutaFinal))//valida que el archivo no haya sido creado ya
{
    crearExcel(dgv, inscripciones, rutaFinal);
}
```

Ambos códigos devuelven false, lo cual no tiene sentido. Si conocen otra forma de validar que el archivo exista se las agradecería.Tengo los permisos de lectura/escritura.

Comment: fuera de tema... cambia el formateo de fecha, aqui tienes ejemplos https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Cual valor tiene rutaFinal?  Es valido?  Tiene (el id que corre VisualStudio) permisos para ver la carpeta?

Comment: Tambien puede simplificar ruta con el "string literal", como así  ruta = @"C:\\Respaldo Sport Gym\" + ... etc.

Comment: El tema del formato de fecha lo manejo así por el hecho de que windows no permite / en los nombres de archivos. He intentado con otros método, pero me devuelve info de mas o los nombres en ingles. Con respecto a los permisos, los tengo ya que puedo crear directorios y archivos, el problema es que intenta crear el archivo aunque ya este, entonces sale una ventana de excel preguntando si quiero sobrescribir.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh y la extension el archivo???? donde esta?

Comment: ._. olvide la extensión del archivo, olvide que solo toma extensión .xls cuando el archivo no existe y el método crearExcel se ejecuta y le da esa extensión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias poner el codigo con un poco mas de orden y no duplicar tanto, algo como esto

```
public void respaldarInfo(DataGridView dgv)
{
    string ruta = string.Format(@"C:\Respaldo Sport Gym\{0:MMMMyyyy}", DateTime.Now);
    string excel = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}.xsl", DateTime.Now);
    string rutaFinal = Path.Combine(ruta, excel);

    if(dgv == null)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para guardar");
         return;
    }
    
    if(File.Exists(rutaFinal))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("El archivo ya existe");
        return;
    }
    
    if (!Directory.Exists(ruta))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
    }

    Service_Inscripcion service = new Service_Inscripcion();
    IList<DTO_Inscripcion> inscripciones = service.getInscripciones();

    if (inscripciones == null && inscripciones.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para guardar", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return
        
    }

    crearExcel(dgv,inscripciones,rutaFinal); 

}
```

Recuerda definir una extension para el archivo, tiene que ser `.xsl` o `.xslx`

Comment: Era la extensión como decís, yo erróneamente asumí que rutaFinal ya venia con la extensión .xls y no me di cuenta que esa extensión sola la toma cuando el archivo NO esta creado y el método crearExcel() lo crea y se la asigna. Gracias, saliendo de esto, hay forma de que con mi código los archivos se creen con formato .xlsx en vez de .xls???

Comment: @FrancoTorres Ayer coloque una respuesta a una pregunta tuya anterior, en esa respuesta coloque como se guarda un archivo con formato .xlsx. Además te voy a dar una recomendación, cuando tengo dudas sobre como programar algo usando `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` pues sencillamente, abro un libro de excel vacío y activo las opciones de programación con  VB para aplicaciones, inicio la grabación de una macro y hago las operaciones que deseo programar, después de hechas todas las operaciones, termino la grabación de la macro, la abro en modo edición y allí tengo como se programan en código VB.

Comment: Recomendaria no uses las libreris de interop de office, usa librerias basadas en `open xml`, como ser https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML, agregas la libreria usando nuget, lo bueno es que no necesitas tener office instalado para crear el excel

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sé tu error... según https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-3.1, tu error puede ser que no tienes ciertos permisos, asegúrate de tener permisos de lectura antes y vuelve a ejecutar